# Can't close figure window using pylab from EPD

Tags: python, matplotlib, enthought

When I am using pylab in ipython notebook I try to close a figure and nothing happens except the toolbar with the pan and zoom options disappears. After this happens when I attempt to plot a new figure I get this:

PyAssertionError: C++ Assertion "wxAssertFailure" failed at ....\crc\msw\app.cpp(703) in wxAPP() Yield called recursively.

There is probably a lot of other output in the cmd window that I could post here as well if it helps. I've seen a solution to this problem here:

```
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3553/
```

Which was to set --pylab=wx when starting the notebook but this does not work for me. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? I've been having a lot of trouble with EPD trying to get Cython to work with mingw as well...I wonder if somehow it's related. I ran the same code with my Anaconda distribution and I have no problems so I'm not quite sure where to begin on this one.